# How to position a drop down list nav bar inside header in html css

Tags: html, css, nav

I am having trouble stacking up the elements inside the nav bar next to each other. 
Here's how it looks:

[image]

I want the nav elements to be side by side of each other.

Here's HTML code

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=".">COMPANY</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=".">OVERVIEW</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">CEO MESSAGE</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">LEADERSHIP</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">INVESTORS</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">AFFILIATION</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href=".">PRODUCTS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=".">OVERVIEW</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">PRODUCTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">APPLICATION</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">USAGE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href=".">PARTNER PROGRAM</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=".">PARTNER PROGRAM</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">BECOME A PARTNER</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href=".">LEARN ABOUT WGIG</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=".">OVERVIEW</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">VIDEOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">INDUSTRY ARTICLES</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">WHITE PAPERS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href=".">MEDIA CENTER</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=".">LATEST NEWS</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">PRESS RELEASES</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">MEDIA COVERAGE</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">EVENTS</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">AFFILIATION</a></li>
                        <li><a href=".">MEDIA KIT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Here's the CSS

**CSS:**

```
#navbar  {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 25%;
    border: 5px solid green ;
    width: 55%;
    height: 100%;
}

#navbar ul {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}

#navbar li {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;  
    float: left;

}

#navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    color:lime;
    height:30px;
    width:40px;
    display: block;
}
#navbar ul ul {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
#navbar ul li:hover ul {
    display:block;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `<ul>` should be relatively positioned. Setting your `<a>` at a fixed 40px wide isn't such a great idea (nor is it necessary) as most of the text within is more than 40px. Also: your menu items will wrap (stack) unless you set a min-width on their container.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/RKRWQ/1/